# Problemas com <p:ajax> no primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Bom dia amigos! Sou iniciante em Java e estou tentando desenvolver um sistema para gestão de igreja. Depois de muitas tentativas, conseguir fazer o ajax funcionar, porém não estou conseguindo recuperar o id do estado que foi selecionado no selectOneMenu. O id retornado é sempre null. Segue trechos do código:

```
<h:form id="formMembroCadastro">
    <h:panelGrid id="panel2" columns="4">
        <p:outputLabel for="estado" value="Estado: " 
                   style="margin-left: 30px" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#
                     {membroBean.membro.endereco.bairro.cidade.estado}"
                     readonly="#{membroBean.acao == 'Consultar'}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{membroBean.getCidadesDoBanco}"
                    immediate="true" update=":formMembroCadastro:cidade" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Escolha o estado"
                          noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{membroBean.estados}" var="estado"
                           itemValue="#{estado.id}" itemLabel="#
                           {estado.nome}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Já mudei várias coisas, tipo @ViewScoped, @SessionScoped, event, listener, update.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MembroBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Membro membro = new Membro();
    private Estado estado;

    public void getCidadesDoBanco() {
        System.out.println(estado.getId());
        cidades = new DAO<Cidade>(Cidade.class).listaGeral();
    }
}
```

Quando coloco

```
System.out.println(Estado.class);
```

imprime "class br.com.igreja.modelo.Estado".

Desde já agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Verifiquei que está ocorrendo o seguinte erro: "Erro de conversão ao definir o valor '3' para 'null Converter". Sendo que o valor 3 é o id do estado selecionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `p:selectOneMenu` está esperando um objeto *Estado* mas você está passando o id do estado.
Você pode alterar o xhtml:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#
                 {membroBean.membro.endereco.bairro.cidade.estado}"
                 readonly="#{membroBean.acao == 'Consultar'}">
        ...
        <f:selectItems value="#{membroBean.estados}" var="estado"
                       itemValue="#{estado}" itemLabel="#
                       {estado.nome}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder André! Além de aplicar sua dica, também utilizei o conversor do omnifaces.